# How to convert two almost identical methods in one method?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have a .net core appllication and I have two mothods. One for the overview page and one for the detail page.

The two methods, are using a two different methods. But these two different methods are almost identical. Only is pas a different parameter in each method:

so this are the two almost identical methods:

```
 public class EcheqSubmission{

public EcheqSubmissionStatusApi StatusDbToApi(EcheqSubmissionStatus dbStatus, EcheqSubmissionInfoApi echeqSubmissionInfoApi)
        {
            EcheqSubmissionStatusApi status;
           // EcheqSubmissionInfoApi echeqSubmissionInfoApi = new EcheqSubmissionInfoApi();

            if (echeqSubmissionInfoApi.ValidUntilUtc < DateTime.Now)
            {
                return EcheqSubmissionStatusApi.Expired;
            }
            else
            {

                switch (dbStatus)
                {
                    case EcheqSubmissionStatus.New:
                        status = EcheqSubmissionStatusApi.New;
                        break;
                    case EcheqSubmissionStatus.Active:
                        status = EcheqSubmissionStatusApi.Active;
                        break;
                    case EcheqSubmissionStatus.Submitted:
                        status = EcheqSubmissionStatusApi.Submitted;
                        break;                   
                    default:
                        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(dbStatus), dbStatus, "Not a valid status enum");
                }
            }
            return status

}


public EcheqSubmissionStatusApi StatusDbToApi(EcheqSubmissionStatus dbStatus, EcheqSubmissionApi echeqSubmissionInfoApi)
        {
            EcheqSubmissionStatusApi status;
            // EcheqSubmissionInfoApi echeqSubmissionInfoApi = new EcheqSubmissionInfoApi();

            if (echeqSubmissionInfoApi.ValidUntilUtc < DateTime.Now)
            {
                return EcheqSubmissionStatusApi.Expired;
            }
            else
            {

                switch (dbStatus)
                {
                    case EcheqSubmissionStatus.New:
                        status = EcheqSubmissionStatusApi.New;
                        break;
                    case EcheqSubmissionStatus.Active:
                        status = EcheqSubmissionStatusApi.Active;
                        break;
                    case EcheqSubmissionStatus.Submitted:
                        status = EcheqSubmissionStatusApi.Submitted;
                        break;               
                    default:
                        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(dbStatus), dbStatus, "Not a valid status enum");
                }
            }
            return status;
        }
    }
}
```

And this are the two methods that are using the almost identical methods:
So this method is for the detail page

```
private static EcheqSubmissionApi ConvertToApi(EcheqSubmission submission, EcheqDefinition definition,
           bool includeAnswers, bool includePages, string assignedByName)
        {
            var result =  new EcheqSubmissionApi
            {
                Id = submission.Id,
                SubmittedOnUtc = submission.SubmittedOnUtc,
                AssignedByOrgId = submission.AssignedByOrgId,
                AssignedByProfId = submission.AssignedByProfId,
                AssignedByProfName = assignedByName,
                AssignedOnUtc = submission.AssignedOnUtc,
                AssignedToId = submission.AssignedToId,
                ValidUntilUtc = submission.ValidUntilUtc,
              //  Status = submission.Status.StatusDbToApi(),
                Definition = definition != null ? EcheqDefinitionConverter.DefinitionDbToApi(definition, noPages: !includePages) : null,
                Answers = includeAnswers ? submission.Answers : null,
                InitialValues = includeAnswers ? submission.InitialValues : null,
                CurrentPage = submission.CurrentPage,
                Progress = submission.Progress
            };

            result.Status = submission.StatusDbToApi(submission.Status, result);

            return result;

        }
```

and this method is for the overview page:

```
 private static EcheqSubmissionInfoApi ConvertToPartialApi(EcheqSubmission submission)
        {

            var result = new EcheqSubmissionInfoApi
            {
                Id = submission.Id,
                //Status = submission.StatusDbToApi(submission.Status,),
                DefinitionId = submission.DefinitionId,
                SubmittedOnUtc = submission.SubmittedOnUtc,
                AssignedByOrgId = submission.AssignedByOrgId,
                AssignedByProfId = submission.AssignedByProfId,
                AssignedOnUtc = submission.AssignedOnUtc,
                AssignedToId = submission.AssignedToId,
                ValidUntilUtc = submission.ValidUntilUtc,
                CurrentPage = submission.CurrentPage,
                Progress = submission.Progress
            };

            result.Status = submission.StatusDbToApi(submission.Status, result);

            return result;

        }
```

So my  question is: how to combine the two switch case methods in on method?

Thank you

so like this:

```
        public EcheqSubmissionStatusApi StatusDbToApi(EcheqSubmissionStatus dbStatus, EcheqSubmissionInfoApi echeqSubmissionInfoApi = null, EcheqSubmissionApi echeqSubmissionoApi = null)
        {
            EcheqSubmissionStatusApi status;


            var validuntil = echeqSubmissionInfoApi != null ? echeqSubmissionInfoApi.ValidUntilUtc : (echeqSubmissionoApi != null ? echeqSubmissionoApi.ValidUntilUtc : null);
            if (validuntil < DateTime.Now)
            {
                return EcheqSubmissionStatusApi.Expired;
            }
            else
            {

                switch (dbStatus)
                {
                    case EcheqSubmissionStatus.New:
                        status = EcheqSubmissionStatusApi.New;
                        break;
                    case EcheqSubmissionStatus.Active:
                        status = EcheqSubmissionStatusApi.Active;
                        break;
                    case EcheqSubmissionStatus.Submitted:
                        status = EcheqSubmissionStatusApi.Submitted;
                        break;

                    case EcheqSubmissionStatus.Expired:
                        status = EcheqSubmissionStatusApi.Expired;
                        break;
                    default:
                        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(dbStatus), dbStatus, "Not a valid status enum");
                }
            }
            return status;
        }
```

oke, I have done this:

```
 public static EcheqSubmissionStatusApi StatusDbToApi(this EcheqSubmissionStatus dbStatus, DateTime dateTime)
```

But what I have to pass here then?

```
   Status = submission.Status.StatusDbToApi( ),
```

I have it like this:

```
public EcheqSubmissionStatusApi StatusDbToApi(EcheqSubmissionStatus dbStatus, DateTime ValidUntilUtc)
        {
            EcheqSubmissionStatusApi status;

            if (ValidUntilUtc < DateTime.Now)
            {
                return EcheqSubmissionStatusApi.Expired;
            }
            else
            {

                switch (dbStatus)
                {
                    case EcheqSubmissionStatus.New:
                        status = EcheqSubmissionStatusApi.New;
                        break;
                    case EcheqSubmissionStatus.Active:
                        status = EcheqSubmissionStatusApi.Active;
                        break;
                    case EcheqSubmissionStatus.Submitted:
                        status = EcheqSubmissionStatusApi.Submitted;
                        break;

                    case EcheqSubmissionStatus.Expired:
                        status = EcheqSubmissionStatusApi.Expired;
                        break;
                    default:
                        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(dbStatus), dbStatus, "Not a valid status enum");
                }
            }
            return status;
```

and this:

```
 private static EcheqSubmissionApi ConvertToApi(EcheqSubmission submission, EcheqDefinition definition,
            bool includeAnswers, bool includePages, string assignedByName)
        {
            var result = new EcheqSubmissionApi
            {
                Id = submission.Id,
                SubmittedOnUtc = submission.SubmittedOnUtc,
                AssignedByOrgId = submission.AssignedByOrgId,
                AssignedByProfId = submission.AssignedByProfId,
                AssignedByProfName = assignedByName,
                AssignedOnUtc = submission.AssignedOnUtc,
                AssignedToId = submission.AssignedToId,
                ValidUntilUtc = submission.ValidUntilUtc,
                Status = submission.StatusDbToApi(result.ValidUntilUtc),
                Definition = definition != null ? EcheqDefinitionConverter.DefinitionDbToApi(definition, noPages: !includePages) : null,
                Answers = includeAnswers ? submission.Answers : null,
                InitialValues = includeAnswers ? submission.InitialValues : null,
                CurrentPage = submission.CurrentPage,
                Progress = submission.Progress
            };

            result.Status = submission.StatusDbToApi(submission.Status, result.ValidUntilUtc);

            return result;
        }
```

But I get this error:

```
cannot use local variable, before it is used


   Status = submission.StatusDbToApi(result.ValidUntilUtc),
```

Comment: Can EcheqSubmissionApi and EcheqSubmissionInfoApi share a common interface?

Comment: You can use optional Parameter for EcheqSubmissionApi and EcheqSubmissionInfoApi

Comment: Minor thing: `echeqSubmissionInfoApi.ValidUntilUtc < DateTime.Now` => `DateTime.UtcNow`?

Comment: Thank you. But can you give an example

Comment: Extract common properties of `EcheqSubmissionInfoApi` and `EcheqSubmissionApi` to some base class. Create one method with parameters `EcheqSubmission submission, YourBaseClass echeqSubmissionInfo`.

Comment: Jeroen.The logic is correct.  But what exactly do you mean?

Comment: Zeecode. But how to do that? Thank you

Comment: Can somebody give an example how to refactor this? Thank you

Comment: @SᴇM. Can you give example/ Thank you

Comment: The only thing you are getting from the second parameter is the DateTime (ValidUntilUtc). So simply change your second parameter to a DateTime and when calling it, pass the appropriate value from the two classes.

Comment: @JonathanWillcock. oke I updated the post. can you look at it.

Comment: It simply becomes `result.Status = submission.StatusDbToApi(submission.Status, result.ValidUntilUtc);`

Comment: yes,. oke. But what about this?  if (echeqSubmissionInfoApi.ValidUntilUtc < DateTime.Now)
            {
                return EcheqSubmissionStatusApi.Expired;
            } I cant do this anymore

Comment: @JonathanWillcock  Because I dont pass a class anymore but a datetime in the switch case. SO how to pass the ValidUntilUtc

Comment: Call the second parameter validUntilUtc and then refer to it in the method simply with`if (validUntilUtc < DateTime.Now)`

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1:By Creating common base class**

```
    public class EcheqSubmissionBase
    {

        public string ValidUntilUtc { get; set; }
    }


    public class EcheqSubmissionStatus : EcheqSubmissionBase
    {
       public string NonCommonPropertyX { get; set; }

    }

    public class EcheqSubmissionInfoApi : EcheqSubmissionBase
    {

        public string NonCommonPropertyY { get; set; }
    }
```

Calling method

```
    var _dbstatusobj = new EcheqSubmissionStatus();
    var EcheqSubmissionInfoApiObject = new EcheqSubmissionInfoApi();

    var result = StatusDbToApi(_dbstatusobj, EcheqSubmissionInfoApi);
```

One Method with base class as parameter

```
   public EcheqSubmissionStatusApi StatusDbToApi(EcheqSubmissionStatus dbStatus,        EcheqSubmissionBase EcheqSubmissionBase)
       {
           EcheqSubmissionStatusApi status;
    // EcheqSubmissionInfoApi echeqSubmissionInfoApi = new EcheqSubmissionInfoApi();

    if (EcheqSubmissionBase.ValidUntilUtc < DateTime.Now)
    {
        return EcheqSubmissionStatusApi.Expired;
    }
    else
    {

        switch (dbStatus)
        {
            case EcheqSubmissionStatus.New:
                status = EcheqSubmissionStatusApi.New;
                break;
            case EcheqSubmissionStatus.Active:
                status = EcheqSubmissionStatusApi.Active;
                break;
            case EcheqSubmissionStatus.Submitted:
                status = EcheqSubmissionStatusApi.Submitted;
                break;
            default:
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(dbStatus), dbStatus, "Not a valid status enum");
        }
    }
    return status

       }
```

**Solution 2 : Optional Parameter**

```
   public EcheqSubmissionStatusApi StatusDbToApi(EcheqSubmissionStatus dbStatus, EcheqSubmissionStatus echeqSubmissionStatus=null, EcheqSubmissionInfoApi echeqSubmissionInfoApi=null )
{
    EcheqSubmissionStatusApi status;
    // EcheqSubmissionInfoApi echeqSubmissionInfoApi = new EcheqSubmissionInfoApi();

    var validuntil = echeqSubmissionStatus != null ? echeqSubmissionStatus.ValidUntilUtc : (echeqSubmissionInfoApi != null ? echeqSubmissionInfoApi.ValidUntilUtc : null);

    if (validuntil < DateTime.Now)
    {
        return EcheqSubmissionStatusApi.Expired;
    }
    else
    {

        switch (dbStatus)
        {
            case EcheqSubmissionStatus.New:
                status = EcheqSubmissionStatusApi.New;
                break;
            case EcheqSubmissionStatus.Active:
                status = EcheqSubmissionStatusApi.Active;
                break;
            case EcheqSubmissionStatus.Submitted:
                status = EcheqSubmissionStatusApi.Submitted;
                break;
            default:
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(dbStatus), dbStatus, "Not a valid status enum");
        }
    }
    return status

}
```

Comment: oke, thank you, but one parameter: EcheqSubmissionStatus echeqSubmissionStatus=null has to be:  EcheqSubmissionInfoApi echeqSubmissionInfoApi = null isnt?

Comment: HI thank you of course for your effort. But a datetime parameter fixed it